# How can I add a value in a document's array on Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My Cloud Firestore database looks like this:

[image: Cloud Firestore database]

My goal is to add "789" in the `number` array, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`arrayUnion()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#.arrayUnion):

```
......
const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc('1');

return userRef.update({
  numbers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('789')
});
......
```

See the corresponding doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array (in addition to the link above)

**Complete example:** Below is the code of a Cloud Function that is triggered when you add a document in the `trigger` collection. It will update the user doc with id = 1, as you request in your question.

```
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
  .document('trigger/{triggerId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const userRef = admin
      .firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc('1');

    return userRef.update({
      numbers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('789')
    });
  });
```

Comment: What this statement `return` means in the context of a cloud function? I'm used to write my "answer" in the response field and I've never used `return` once in a cloud function.

Comment: `return` is actually **key** in the context of a Cloud Function, as you must return the promises returned by the asynchronous operations. You will get more details on this aspect by watching the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: I've added an example to my answer. Hope it helps!